# GCDA files not generated in the device

Tags: ios, iphone, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have a project that cannot be run on a simulator. It uses location services and beacons. I wanted to unit test this on the device. But I am not able to generate the GCDA files. I have followed these:
[Blog](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/10/xcode-coverage/)
[apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1514/_index.html)

I am currently getting the error:
profiling: /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Access-guzrgfyvztojztdgzxnolbjsntjf/Build/Intermediates/Access.build/Code Coverage-iphoneos/AccessTests.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Login Tests.gcda: cannot open: No such file or directory

I am trying to run unit tests on a physical device

any help would be appriciated

Comment: What have you tried? What are the specific issues you are facing? Do you get any error messages or warnings?

Comment: @Tobias sorry.. have a look at the updated question